# How to set a data type for a column with ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I see a lot of examples in documentation where data type for a cell is set:

```
ws.Cell(1, 1).SetDataType(XLCellValues.Text);
```

But when I try to set a data type for a column:

```
ws.Column(1).SetDataType(XLCellValues.Text)
```

ClosedXML generates a 5MB file and data type is not actually set.

This operation works as expected in Excel (right-click on the column header, format cells, ...).

If it is a limitation of ClosedXML, can it be easily fixed, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update for version 0.100:**

Starting with version 0.100 you don't need to set a datatype for a cell, because the type of the cell value will be used.

From the [migration guide](https://docs.closedxml.io/en/latest/migrations/migrate-to-0.100.html#setdatatype-methods-removed):

> **SetDataType methods removed**
> Method SetDataType has been removed from all interfaces (IXLCell, IXLColumn, IXLColumns, IXLRange …). There is no replacement, if you need to reinterpret existing data, do it in application code and set a new value with a specific type.

---

**For older versions (up to 0.97):**

ClosedXML sets the data type for all cells in the column, down to the maximum (row 1 million or so). Use this to only set the data type for the used cells in the column:

```
ws.Column(1).CellsUsed().SetDataType(XLDataType.Text);
```

Furthermore, the data type in ClosedXML is not the same as the cell format in Excel (have a look at the example file from the documentation to see the difference).

Comment: Yeah i was using colum and setdatatype without the 'cellused' filter. turns out the process takes forever.

Comment: There is not a "Column" property. Could it be because I am running a different version of ClosedXml?

Comment: If you want to exclude the top row, you can do this: var lastCell = ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
string cells = "2:" + lastCell;
ws.Column(5).Cells(cells).SetDataType(XLDataType.Number);

Comment: i have something like 06-23 which is being converted by excel like 2021-06-23. how do i stop getting it converted.

Comment: I solved using     ws.Cell(row, 1).SetValue<string>(yourinput);

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using
ws.Cell(row, 1).Value = myinput.ToString();
"myinput" in my case was a double

Comment: This wont help for me. Mine was a string but still cast to be a double.