# C# ClosedXML WorkSheets Add's 1048576 empty rows

Tags: c#, rows, worksheet, closedxml

I've been trying to find a solution for this but haven't been able to find any yet. So what is happening is that when I do:

`IXLWorksheet sheetSave = wb.Worksheets.Add("SheetName");`

I get an Excel sheet that as 1048576 rows and 20Columns. If I send a datatable same thing happens, it places the table but the sheet still as 1048576 rows, This makes the file have a size of 5MB with about 200x20 cells filled.

So does anyone know how to solve this? A way to force the range to a certain size, like the size o rows from the datatable.

Thank you,
any extra information just ask.

Added by request in answer:

Here is the method used to export the datatable to excel

```
private void exportExcel(DataTable data)
    {
        XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();

        IXLWorksheet sheetSave = wb.Worksheets.Add(data, "list"); 

        DialogResult saveDialogResult = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if ((saveDialogResult == DialogResult.OK) && (saveFileDialog1.FileName != null))
        {
            wb.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code around creating the worksheet. It looks like you are taking an existing worksheet (wb ?) and saving it to a new IXLWorksheet

Comment: @Mike159 I edited the question with the method to export the datatable.

Comment: Are you intending to use sheetSave?
writing `wb.Worksheets.Add(data, "list");` should get the same result

Comment: @Mike159 first of all thank you for replying. Yes I will use the sheetSave in other calls, and when you asked that I went searching for the error in other parts of the code and found the problem and then solution after some new search. I was setting the datatype, in another method, for the column and not for the cells used in that column. The solution is here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775423/how-to-set-a-data-type-for-a-column-with-closedxml) 
How do I close this? And do a duplicate to the link I added?

Comment: You can mark the question as a duplicate, or put the answer here yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further searching\debugging I found I was setting the datatype in another method for the column and not for the cells used. So all the cells from row(1) to row(1058576) were being filled. Got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775423/how-to-set-a-data-type-for-a-column-with-closedxml). 
Thank you all.