# ClosedXML - Setting data type for cell does not work

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

I have similar question about ClosedXML, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775423/how-to-set-a-data-type-for-a-column-with-closedxml) but a little bit diferent.
The SetDataType method does not work.
For example, I have value
`string dps = "3.12.02"`
which is not a date nor number, it is valid text.

When I do this:

`ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = dps;
ws.Cell(1, 1).SetDataType(XLCellValues.Text);`

and save the file and then open it in Excel, it still convert it to some rubish like `37593`
I tried to put it before and after setting the value, no change.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `.Value` method tries to guess the type of the value that you're setting. In your case, the value is a valid (i.e. parseable) `DateTime`, which are internally stored as numbers.

To set a value explicitly, without guessing, use:

```
string dps = "3.12.02";
ws.Cell(1, 1).SetValue(dps);
```

Comment: Thank you !! Both scenarios work perfectly, but due to my low reputation I can't upvote :( so at least I want to thank you this way :)

Comment: Pleasure. I've also updated the doctext of IXCell.Value to hopefully make it clearer that data types will be guessed if you use this method. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/commit/93f42089f952c4d71912a0749c770035c4a494a4

Comment: wish I have known this sooner. saved me plenty of frustration

Answer (score 2):

Although I can't tell you why it's not working, one easy way is to prepend your string with an apostrophe (`'`). This forces Excel to treat everything that follows as text.

```
string dps = "'3.12.02";
ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = dps;
```

Comment: Thank you !! Both scenarios work perfectly, but due to my low reputation I can't upvote :( so at least I want to thank you this way :)

Answer (score 2):

I realize you are trying to set a Text value but I have found that LibreOffice created Excel files seem to somehow mess up ClosedXMLs ability to set a column to a DateTime data type.

```
// What I tried without success.
cell.Clear(XLClearOptions.All);
cell.SetValue<DateTime>((DateTime)cellValue);
cell.SetDataType(XLDataType.DateTime);
```

Nothing I did would fix the issue until I recreated the spreadsheet in Excel.

```
// This worked just fine on a proper Excel file
cell.SetValue((DateTime)cellValue);
```

As soon as I opened and saved the spreadsheet with LibreOffice, the ability to correctly set the column type disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

For setting the cell data type of a particular column one can use the below function from the closedXML

```
ws.Column(2).Style.NumberFormat.SetNumberFormatId(
(int)XLPredefinedFormat.Number.Text);
```

ws is the worksheet object,

Here Column(2) is the second column from excel sheet

Note: The Column count in excel starts from 1 and not 0

Comment: This is the only working solution for version 0.102.0 if you don't want to have the leading  `'`.